# exc_arithmetic error with simulator only, assigning UICollectionView flowlayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios-simulator, xcode7-beta5

Im trying to assign a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to a `UICollectionView` and it runs fine on a physical device but simulators break, with a signal:

> EXC_ARITHMETIC(code=EXC_i386_DIV, subcode=0x0)

This only happens on a simulator, it is my understanding that this is usually a division by 0 error, but I dont see how thats possible for my implementation

**Code:**

```
let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

flowLayout.itemSize =  CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width * 0.67,
                                      self.collectionView!.frame.height - 10)

flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal

self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Furthermore, i get the signal at this line: `self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout`

and the view bounds are : WIDTH: 277.38 HEIGHT: 75.0

Any help, or alternatives would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `self.view.bounds.width` 0?

Comment: @jtbandes no printing out the dimens gives WIDTH: 277.38 HEIGHT: 75.0

Answer (score 20):

Helped to call

> reloadData

before

> setCollectionViewLayout

Comment: Worked for me too, it would be great to know why.

Answer (score 6):

I got the exact same issue on a old code I am working on and it appears that I was calling this code from a wrong method. I moved it in more appropriate place, viewDidLoad or init and it works.

Comment: Sounds like only half the solution here. You are supposed to be able to change the collectionViewLayout at any time.